# async programming trying to understand how await works

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

So I am learning some basic async programming and following this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/ However the output I am getting is different to what I am expecting.

Here is my code:

```
private async void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   await TestAsync();
   Console.WriteLine("terminate");
}

private async Task TestAsync()
{
   string str = await Todo();
   await Task.Delay(500);  //added await operator as per FCin advice
   Console.WriteLine(str);
}

private async Task<string> Todo()
{
   await Task.Delay(3000); //added await operator as per FCin advice
   return "return from async task";
}
```

Starting with clicking btn1, the btn1_Click method will fire.
First it will call TestAsync().
Since the first line of the TestAsync method is to await an async method, my understanding is that at this point the await operator should suspend TestAsync and return control to the caller of TestAsync, which is btn1_Click.
This should print "terminate" and then the program should patiently wait for TestAsync to complete and eventually print ""return from async task".
However the output I get is is reverse order and I am trying to understand why.

So I have amended it so that TestAsync is now awaited in the btn1_Click method. Also I have changed thread sleeping to task delay, but I still get the same output...

Edit2: The code I am using as an example

```
// 1. Three things to note in the signature:  
//  - The method has an async modifier.   
//  - The return type is Task or Task<T>. (See "Return Types" section.)  
//    Here, it is Task<int> because the return statement returns an integer.  
//  - The method name ends in "Async."  
async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()  
{   
// 2. You need to add a reference to System.Net.Http to declare client.  
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();  

// 3. GetStringAsync returns a Task<string>. That means that when you await 
// the task you'll get a string (urlContents).  
Task<string> getStringTask = 
client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");  

// 4 .You can do work here that doesn't rely on the string from 
//GetStringAsync.  
DoIndependentWork();  

// 5. The await operator suspends AccessTheWebAsync.  
//  - AccessTheWebAsync can't continue until getStringTask is complete.  
//  - Meanwhile, control returns to the caller of AccessTheWebAsync.  
//  - Control resumes here when getStringTask is complete.   
//  - The await operator then retrieves the string result from getStringTask.  
string urlContents = await getStringTask;  

// 6. The return statement specifies an integer result.  
// Any methods that are awaiting AccessTheWebAsync retrieve the length value.  
return urlContents.Length;  
}
```

Comment: You never await the call to `TestAsync` in `btn1_Click` so you essentially fire/forget the returned task.

Comment: Also don't use `Thread.Sleep` instead await `Task.Delay`.

Comment: Debugger is a great tool to understand this. Step through the code line by line and it’ll show what’s happening. As mentioned, Thread.Sleep will just block the execution and not let anything continue.

Comment: It will return control only if it actually has to wait for the task to finish, there is no async operation to await in your Todo method, so it runs like there was no async/wait

Comment: you can watch my video on async programming ,i explained how it works with real world example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bm9D5GIa6fA&t=17s

Comment: __`await`__  the `Task.Delay()` calls. Also read the warnings the compiler produces.

Comment: Continually changing the code in the question makes it **very** difficult to understand. E.g. as it currently stands, it makes FCins answer difficult to understand because now your code *looks exactly like the code in their answer*. And your narrative hasn't been updated to match the changing code. I'd suggest reverting back to an earlier version which clearly matches the advice FCin could then give.

Comment: i've edited it for the final time to reflect fcins advice, and won't be makin any more changes. which part of my narrative do you think doesn't match with the change in code?

Comment: _output I am getting is different to what I am expecting_ What do you expect and what are you getting. It would be helpful if that was in your question.

Comment: That is in the question! I expect to get "terminate" and then "return from async task" in that order but instead I get the statements in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

await does what it says, it waits. When you hit `await` it doesn't go to a caller method, It waits until `Todo` is finished. Now why use `async/await` if it waits? Because during this wait, it does other work. It keeps your UI running. It handles messages from message queue, such as clicking buttons, drawing controls, calculating if your cursor hit any bounding boxes that would highlight a control, etc.

Your code right now is completely synchronous, because you are not awaiting `Task.Delay`. You probably even get a warning for each not awaited method.

Here is how this code should execute:

1. Wait 3000 ms
2. Return "return from async task"
3. Wait 500 ms
4. Print "return from async task"
5. Print "terminate"

Code:

```
private async void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   await TestAsync();
   Console.WriteLine("terminate");
}

private async Task TestAsync()
{
   string str = await Todo();
   await Task.Delay(500);
   Console.WriteLine(str);
}

private async Task<string> Todo()
{
   await Task.Delay(3000);
   return "return from async task";
}
```

Comment: actually i've posted the code i'm following in the question, please see comment section 5 where it gives the impression that on encountering an await operator, the method which contains the await operator gets suspended and control is returned to the caller of the method. I guess I am interepreting this wrong but I am not sure how..